# Can I use the 'WHERE' clause in an 'INSERT' command in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

I am using SQLite3 with Python. I am quite certain that the '`WHERE`' clause does not work with '`INSERT`' operation, but I really need to have a workaround to solve my issue. I have the following prepopulated database:

[image]

I was hoping to come up with an SQL statement where I can add the `VALUES` **('2021-01-13', '36.8')** to the table `WHERE` **family='FAA' `AND` model='MAA'**. I have read a lot of stuff online but still no luck on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an *update* here:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET date = '2021-01-13', duration = 36.8
WHERE family = 'FAA' AND model = 'MAA';
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to update your table, insert is only for new rows. When you want to change a value, you must to use update statement.

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET date = '2021-01-13', duration = '36.8'
 WHERE  family='FAA' AND model='MAA';
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html